# XmlDocument.Load get stuck?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I'm trying to load the xml files from path in windows Forms Application.

```
    public static ClassLayout GetClassLayout()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"Files\Class.xml");
        return Serializer.XmlDeserialize<ClassLayout>(doc.OuterXml);
    }
```

But on reaching the doc.Load line it's getting stuck. I'm not getting any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to combine the path - environment.currentdirectory does not end with a "\"

```
public static ClassLayout GetClassLayout()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,  @"Files\Class.xml"));
    return Serializer.XmlDeserialize<ClassLayout>(doc.OuterXml);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to be sure that `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is what you think it is. If that is correct, the problem is that the value returned will most likely not have a `\` at the end of it, so it is probably looking for something like `C:\WindowsFiles\Class.xml`.

The best way to create directory and file paths is to use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.Path.Combine(v=vs.110).aspx), which will handle trailing slashes:

```
public static ClassLayout GetClassLayout()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Files\Class.xml"));
    return Serializer.XmlDeserialize<ClassLayout>(doc.OuterXml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably appending CurrentDirectory to Files. Try:

```
doc.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Files\Class.xml");
```